# Enter date time in an asp.net mvc application runs on multiple timezone?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For an Asp.Net web application which will run globally, I have a data type of `DateTimeOffset` for the database tables (SQL Server 2012) and model properties.

The Asp.Net Mvc code `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TicketLink)` accept the following format.

> 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM +00:00

It's a little bit ugly for user to enter +00:00 as time zone. (They may even know what the Timezone they are in). What's the best way to avoid entering timezone and handle it correct?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following approach:

1. Store user's timezone id in database
2. Store all time values in local format (with type of DateTime)
3. (optional) If needed, create an additional field (with type of DateTimeOffset). But keep in mind that these values may change once the user decides to change his timezone.
4. Convert from local timezone to universal time when needed.

The main pros for this approach is that ***your user can change his timezone***. You must keep user's timezone in database. And it seems that it is the right way to go, because all the forum software ask for timezone when someone tries to register.

Convert DateTime to DateTimeOffset Utc:

```
        string timezoneId = "W. Europe Standard Time";
        TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezoneId);
        var d = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, tzi.GetUtcOffset(dateTime)).ToUniversalTime();
```

(you can omit ToUniversalTime)